# What is meaning of this syntax Form<?> in Java?

Tags: java

I don't know whether I am asking silly question or not. but I am not aware of this thing as I am new to Java.

I came across a syntax like :

```
Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("userForm") {
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit() {

             /*some code here*/
        }
    };
```

Can someone please explain me the use of this syntax? I can't move forward without understanding this concept?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/, more specially https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: it specifies an unbound wildcard (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html)

Answer (score 2):

this syntax is using to create generic objects. So you can use generic class for any type of objects. 
For example;

```
Form<String> form = new Form<String>("userForm")`
```

and

```
Form<Double> form = new Form<Double>("userForm")
```

are not same kind of objects. First one is used as String, second one is used as Double.(types are only examples)

```
Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("userForm")
```

usage shows that it's wildcard and it means you can use it any type but is there may be ambigious situations. To avoid ambigious situations, you can declare type of form or anything else.

To see details of generic classes and Collections in Java, here is some tutorials.

[generics](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm)

[collections](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a form var you should specify the type of this form as  but you can use the wildcard  to load any "type"

But to do it you need to add a @overryde annotation because this kind of wildcard is not safe and should be avoided, so if you really want to use it you need to add @overryde to ensure that you know what you are doing.

Cheers !!!